# C# or Java for 2D games

Tags: c#, java

I have been programming in Java (my first language) for about six months and I have started to make some 2D game just as a hobby. I have been looking into switching to C# because the XNA framework looks great for my needs. Would you recommend using C# or Java for programming 2D games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely recommend you to start by using the XNA Framework, because it's easier to learn and you have to do a lot on your own by using the different Java Graphic frameworks.

A good entry point is [coding4fun](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun)

Hope i was able to help you,

Greetings